# Using current limiting diodes instead of resistors

Tags: current, diodes, current-limiting

Most 3D printers have stepper motors that are rated for maybe 2-3 volts, but are usually driven at much higher voltage like 12 or 24 volts. It's possible since the motor drivers are current-limiting; so apparently it's fine to run (at least some) electronic components at voltages much higher than what they are rated for so long as current is limited.

Now I heard of current limiting diodes. While I don't fully understand how they work yet, I wonder if, instead of using a resistor to create a voltage drop when operating electronic parts from a DC source of higher voltage, whether it would be sufficient to simply limit current using a current limiting diode, and whether that would be more energy efficient / would result in less heat?

Comment: *It's possible since the motor drivers are current limiting - so apparently it's fine to run (at least some) electronic components at voltages much higher than what they are rated for so long as current is limited.* These motors are likely PWM **voltage** **controlled**, giving them an effective lower voltage, rather than **current** **controlled** by means of a current limit. There likely is a current limit as **safety feature**.

Comment: The motor drivers aren't current limiting (except as a safety feature); they contain switching voltage converters to provide the appropriate voltage to the motor.

Comment: I think you have some good pointers already for the approach taken in driving the motors. With respect to the CLDs, those are simple N-JFET devices. They are perhaps as good as \$\pm 20\%\$ relative to each other in precision. I've no idea how they would be useful in this circumstance, though.

Comment: See the [AL5809 constant current driver](http://lednique.com/power-supplies/al5809-constant-current-driver/) article (by me).

Comment: @Transistor I think you linked to a non-routable IP address